# How do I copy a file to the clipboard with the terminal?

Tags: files, terminal, file-copy, clipboard, xsel

I'm aware of how to copy the **contents** of file:

```bsh
xsel -b < myfile.txt
```

But this is **not** what I want.

I would like something like this:

```
./file2clip.sh myfile.txt
```

Which would copy `myfile.txt` to the clipboard so then I could `ctrl` + `v` (paste) or right click and paste **the file** anywhere (on the desktop, in the file explorer, etc.).

How can I copy a file/files to the clipboard so that I can paste it with `ctrl` + `v` anywhere in the gui?

Windows equivalent: (powershell)

```
Set-Clipboard -Path myfile.txt
```

Macos equivalent: (applescript)

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
on run args
    set the clipboard to POSIX file (first item of args)
end
```

```bsh
./file2clip.applescript myfile.txt
```

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with `xsel -b < myfile.txt`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, Again, I do **not** want to copy the content of `myfile.txt`. Why? Because then I cannot paste it in the gui with `ctrl` + `v`. I would like to paste the copied file, with `ctrl` + `v` or right click paste in the gui.

Comment: So are you asking how to copy the file's *name* using xsel? if so, you can use any method that streams the name to standard output ex. `printf '%s' myfile.txt | xsel -b` or (in shells that provide here string redirection) `xsel -b <<< myfile.txt`

Comment: @steeldriver, No, All I want to do is `./file2clip.sh myfile.txt` and then be able to **paste** the file anywhere in the gui with `ctrl` + `v` or right click and paste, **Simulating the process of using `ctrl` + `c` while the file is selected**. In your way, I use `xsel -b <<< myfile.txt` but then I **can't** paste the file in the gui with `ctrl` + `v`.

Comment: @lordcommander: ok, I think I got it. And I don't know how do that - it looks like a filemanager-specific operation and I don't use file managers.

Comment: It depends on what you call the *gui* and the file manager being used. No silver bullet there. Which gui/filemanager do you want this to work for?

Comment: @Eduardo Trápani, I'm hoping for it to work for everything. But if I had to choose, probably nautilus or thunar

Comment: How is this question different from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/597981/how-do-i-copy-a-file-to-the-clipboard-in-the-terminal? If it is no different, then please don't repost questions even if they get no answer.

Comment: @Quasímodo, It's better to understand

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it follows as:

1. Install `xclip`, such as:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xclip
   ```
2. Pipe the output into xclip to be copied into the clipboard:

   ```
   cat file | xclip
   ```
3. Paste the text you just copied into a X application:

   ```
   xclip -o
   ```

To paste somewhere else other than an X application, such as a text area of a web page in a browser window, use:

```
cat file | xclip -selection clipboard
```

Consider creating an alias:

```shell
alias "c=xclip"
alias "v=xclip -o"
```

To see how useful this is, imagine I want to open my current path in a new terminal window (there may be other ways of doing it like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on some systems, but this is just for illustration purposes):

- Terminal 1:

  ```
  pwd | c
  ```
- Terminal 2:

  ```
  cd 'v'
  ```

Notice the `` `...` `` around `v`. This executes `v` as a command first and then substitutes it in-place for `cd` to use.

Only copy the content to the X clipboard

Answer (score 0):

Just tested xsel and it works. Have you tried shift+ins? That works for me.

```
$ xsel -b <<< bla
# or
$ xsel -b <<< "bla bla"
# for string with spaces
```

Comment: I'm not trying to copy a string to the clipboard, please read my question again

Comment: Either you want file name or file content. Tertium non datur.

Comment: Neither, the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

How about [`xclip-copyfile`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/xclip-copyfile.1.en) of the `xclip` package?

I didn't test if you then can paste with *Ctrl-v*, but guess its possible.